# Matrix transforms with SpriteBatch overloading - how do you rotate/zoom around a point?

Tags: xna, c#, camera, matrix

I have a transform matrix which works as intended for game objects I want to be completely controlled by my camera:

```
_transform = Matrix.Identity *
    Matrix.CreateTranslation(-_position.X, -_position.Y, 0) *
    Matrix.CreateRotationZ(_rotation) *
    Matrix.CreateTranslation(origin.X, origin.Y, 0) *
    Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(_zoom, _zoom, _zoom));
```

I expose this to my drawing and use the following `SpriteBatch.Begin()` overload:

```
sb.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, 
    BlendState.AlphaBlend, 
    SamplerState.PointClamp, 
    DepthStencilState.None, 
    RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise, 
    null, 
    view.Transform);
```

This works as expected. No problems.

However, I have an object which controls it's own translation as it's a fake star field. I didn't want to have to generate potentially millions of stars to be drawn in order for it to be translated about, so the star field just loops them back to the opposite side if they past the edge of the screen. Zoom just acts really bizarrely. It's not being zoomed into the middle of the screen like it should. At some high zoom value it just swipes off the screen. I initially was having an issue with the rotation but after reordering via trial and error I was able to use the correct sequence of transforms. Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
_transformNoTranslation = Matrix.Identity *
    Matrix.CreateTranslation(origin.X, origin.Y, 0) *
    Matrix.CreateRotationZ(_rotation) *
    Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(_zoom, _zoom, _zoom)) *
    Matrix.CreateTranslation(-Origin.X, -Origin.Y, 0);
```

And here's what it looks like:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0lg-V36M7og

**How do I get the zoom to work correctly?**

As a side question, any ideas as to why the ship jutters at high speeds? I don't plan to ever be at those high speeds during game play so it's not a huge cause for concern. Some kind of precision error with the high translation values?

Comment: try scaling then rotating.

Comment: Exact same issue!

Comment: you have two vectors called origin (one with an uppercase 'O'), are they different?

Comment: It seems like the origin is scaled too. When you translate back it looks like being translated to the scaled value. It might explain why it is going away and not staying in the middle. In your code it seems you're not using the same Origin(upper case and lower case 'O') value back and forth. I would investigate this.

Comment: @Michael.P You are exactly right, the origin is based off of the scale, I needed to use the center of the screen regardless of the same scale instead. How you were able to notice that is a mystery to me! Thank you. Josh Petrie has marked this as a duplicate when my problem had nothing to do with the duplicate's answer, in any case, I wouldn't have been able to fix my problem reading the duplicate. If he changes it back you should answer it so I can I mark this as answered!